# Клиент-серверное приложение

Tags: клиент-сервер

Есть клиент и сервер. При изменение данных на сервере нужно уведомить всех клиентов. Вопрос как лучше организовать этот обмен? Есть следующие варианты:

1. Клиент посылает запросы серверу каждые n минут и обрабатывает полученные данные.
2. Клиент регистрирует себя на сервере и ждет уведомлений. Шаблон Наблюдатель (Observer).

Протокол HTTP. Предполагается что клиентов будет больше 5000.
Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Решение для php/js/html/nginx/memcache:

1) Создаем php файлик, который будет писать в memcache, например:

```
while (true) {
    // write to memcache here
}
```

2) На стороне клиента шлем аякс-запрос по http:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var data = ajax('http://server/static.html');
}, 500);
```

3) Настраиваем nginx так, чтобы по урлу static.html он отдавал то, что Вы положили в memcache без кэширования, т.е. с истекшим сроком.

Все, работает очень быстро и без каких-либо задержек. Проверенно на количестве запросов раз в секунду и посещаемости сайта в 3000 онлайн.

Comment: Сильно, но трудно реализуемо, потому что для каждого пользователя нужно отдавать нужные только ему данные...

Comment: Не вопрос, делайте static#USERID#.html

Уверяю, что разницы сколько мнимых файлов будет - нет. Каждый юзер будет по своему урлу получать свои данные. Если Вы не хотите, чтобы юзеры могли как-нибудь получить данные другого, то нужно будет позаботиться о безопастности и правах доступа. Удачи!

Comment: P.S: Если найдете решение, чтобы сервер отдавал данные клиенту без запроса - дайте знать:)

Comment: Совсем забыл про великий и тормознючий флэш!
Его большой плюс заключается в том, что он умеет создавать одно соединение и постоянно через него гонять данные, это работает еще быстрее, но в том случае, если есть флэш у юзера, что является большим минусом, даже перекрывающим его плюс.

Comment: Недостаток флэша такой же, как и в случае сomet - большое количество одновременных соединений.

Answer (score 0):

мне лично больше нравится второй вариант, но помимо получения уведомления, клиент ещё должен ответить серверу что все понял. таким образом, если от кого-то из клиентов не пришел ответ, через n минут, уведомление для них можно повторить.